# Хранение данных на серверах facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Доброй ночи!

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть ли для Facebook аналог [Хранения данных на серверах ВКонтакте](http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85+%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)? Что-то в документации ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше была такая возможность, но сейчас ее вроде как отключили временно.
[data.setCookie](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/data.setCookie/) - если я правильно понял, то это оно.